# How to properly define a gorm db interface?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to unit test methods that use type `*gorm.DB` and am curious how to properly define an interface that will enable me to test without hitting a db.

Here is a small example of what I want to do:

```
type DBProxy interface {
    Create(values interface{}) *DBProxy
    Update(values interface{}) *DBProxy
}

type TestDB struct{}

func (t *TestDB) Create(values interface{}) *TestDB {
    return t
}

func (t *TestDB) Update(values interface{}) *TestDB {
    return t
}

func Connect() DBProxy {
    return &TestDB{}
}
```

Which results in:

```
cannot use TestDB literal (type *TestDB) as type DBProxy in return argument:
    *TestDB does not implement DBProxy (wrong type for Create method)
            have Create(interface {}) *TestDB
            want Create(interface {}) *DBProxy
```

Any help would be appreciated!

---

UPDATE

Here is my actual application code:

```
package database

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

type DBProxy interface {
    Create(values interface{}) DBProxy
    Update(values interface{}) DBProxy
}

func Connect() DBProxy {
    databaseUrl := os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL")

    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", databaseUrl)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return db
}
```

Which results in:

```
cannot use db (type *gorm.DB) as type DBProxy in return argument:
    *gorm.DB does not implement DBProxy (wrong type for Create method)
            have Create(interface {}) *gorm.DB
            want Create(interface {}) DBProxy
```

Answer (score 1):

`TestDB` methods must return `*DBProxy` to implement `DBProxy`

```
func (t *TestDB) Create(values interface{}) *DBProxy {
    return t
}
func (t *TestDB) Update(values interface{}) *DBProxy {
    return t
}
```

later you will need to assert `CreatedDBProxy.(TestDB)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still a little confused. My goal is to create an interface for `gorm.DB` in order to use a mock in a unit test.

Since I don't have control over what `gorm.DB` methods return, I am unsure of how to correctly define the interface.